# How to do long polling in Outlook (VSTO) which triggers new Windows Form

Tags: c#, outlook, background, task, vsto

I've created a VSTO for Outlook 2016 which does long polling to a SQL database which looks to see if there are messages available for the user (every 5 mins it checks). If a message is available it should display it to the user as the topmost window of the Outlook thread.

I've successfully done this with background workers and tasks, however both of these solutions display the new windows form (message) in their own threads which is NOT the top most window. Users can miss this message because it can be hidden behind outlook.

I need a way of accessing the Outlook Object Model from a Task or Background worker.

Background worker Example:

```cs
public Messenger()
{
   BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

   backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler((object doSender, DoWorkEventArgs doEvent) =>
   {
      try
      {
         SqlConnection messageDB = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

         List<MessageItem> selectResults = new List<MessageItem>();

         string querySelect = $"SELECT ......";

         // Initialize Adapter
         SqlDataAdapter trackerAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(querySelect, messageDB);

         // Initialize empty result dataset.
         DataSet dbDataSet = new DataSet();

         // Fill the results container.
         trackerAdapter.Fill(dbDataSet);

         // Get the data (table).
         DataTable trackerTable = dbDataSet.Tables[0];

         // Get the row data.
         DataRow[] dataResults = trackerTable.Select();

         foreach (DataRow item in dataResults)
         {
            MessageItem tempMessage = new MessageItem();

            tempMessage.id = (int)item.ItemArray[0];
            tempMessage.employeeID = (string)item.ItemArray[1];
            tempMessage.messageEN = (string)item.ItemArray[2];
            tempMessage.messageFR = (string)item.ItemArray[3];
            tempMessage.action = (int)item.ItemArray[4];

            selectResults.Add(tempMessage);
         }

         doEvent.Result = selectResults;
      }
      catch
      {
         // Problem connecting to database. Cancel the running task so it doesn't try again.
         messageCancelTokenSource.Cancel();
      }
   });

   var checkMessages = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {
      while (true)
      {
         // Checks if the task was cancelled.
         if (messageCancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
         {
            break;
         }

         // Execute the job.
         backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

         Thread.Sleep(300000);
      }
   }, messageCancelToken, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
}

private void BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    List<MessageItem> results = e.Result as List<MessageItem>;

    foreach (MessageItem message in messages)
    {
         MessageWindow myMessage = new MessageWindow ( message );

         myMessage.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

I've also tried completely getting rid of the background worker and using only a task:

```cs
Task<Task> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        // SQL Commands 

        // Display message

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    }
}, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not sound like you actually need to access the Outlook Object Model on a secondary thread. The most you actually need is to retrieve the `HWND` of the main Outlook window (e.g. by casting `Application.ActiveExplorer` to `IOleWindow` and calling `IOleWindow.GetWindow`) on the main thread and use that handle later to properly parent your custom form.

Comment: The long polling starts as soon as Outlook is launched (polling is triggered in ThisAddIn_Startup). While i'm not sure the Explorer window is active right at this point I've tried to implement a IOleWindow interface then do something like IOleWindow OutlookWindow = Application.ActiveExplorer() as IOleWindow; but I don't know where to go from here.

I don't know how to convert the IOleWindow to IWin32Window that ShowDialog needs.

Comment: Create your own class that implements the IWin32Window interface. Its Handle property must return the HWND you get from IOleWindow.GetWindow)

Answer (score 0):

Dmitry certainly set me on the right track. However as I'm pretty new to C# and .NET I wasn't able to fill in all the blanks. After combining pieces from here and there below is the solution I found that works.

First, implement your own IOleWindow interface class. I've no idea why we have to do this but we do:

```cs
[ComImport]
[Guid("00000114-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IOleWindow
{
    void GetWindow( out IntPtr phwnd );

    void ContextSensitiveHelp( [In, MarshalAs ( UnmanagedType.Bool) ] bool fEnterMode );
}
```

If you need the IWin32Window object of the Outlook Explorer window immediately then in your ThisAddIn.cs do something like this

```cs
public NativeWindow OutlookWindow;

private void setOutlookWindow()
{
    // Cast the Outlook Explorer window as your IOleWindow interface.
    IOleWindow OutlookExplorerObj = Application.ActiveExplorer() as IOleWindow;

    // This will store the Outlook Explorer window handle.
    IntPtr OutlookExplorerHandle;

    // Assign the window handle.
    OutlookExplorerObj.GetWindow( out OutlookExplorerHandle);

    // Create a blank IWin32Window implementation.
    OutlookWindow = new NativeWindow();

    // Assign the Outlook Explorer window handle to the IWin32Window object.
    OutlookWindow.AssignHandle( OutlookExplorerHandle );
}

private void ThisAddIn_Startup( object sender, System.EventArgs e )
{
    setOutlookWindow();
}
```

Then you can access the window object with Globals.ThisAddIn.OutlookWindow:

```cs
myWindow.ShowDialog( Globals.ThisAddIn.OutlookWindow );
```

This even works from Tasks or Background Workers.